# Cannot open include file pcap.h in QT creator (C1083)

Tags: c++, qt, winpcap

I am trying to link winpcap into my QT creator project.

For that I've added this to my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/WpdPack/Include
LIBS += -LC:/WpdPack/Lib -lwpcap - lpacket
```

When I type `#include <pcap.h>` the code assistant autocompletes but on compile I get `Error:C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pcap.h': No such file or directory`.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the solution pops up after asking the question:

I've found a workaround

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/WpdPack/Include
LIBS += C:/WpdPack/Lib/wpcap.lib
LIBS += C:/WpdPack/Lib/Packet.lib
CONFIG += no_lflags_merge
```

And it builds.